# Python3 super() and generic class

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

I believe a test case is worth a thousand words:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def generate_a(key):
    class A(object):
        def method(self):
            return {'key': key,}
    return A

BaseForB = generate_a(1337)

class B(BaseForB):
    def method(self):
        dict = super(BaseForB, self).method()
        dict.update({'other_key': 0,})
        return dict

EXPECTED = {'other_key': 0, 'key': 1337,}
RESULT = B().method()

if EXPECTED == RESULT:
    print("Ok")
else:
    print("EXPECTED: ", EXPECTED)
    print("RESULT: ", RESULT)
```

This raises:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'method'
```

The question is - how to run `A.method()` in `B.method()` (the thing I tried to do with `super()`)

**edit**

Here's more appropriate test case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def generate_a(key):
    class A(object):
        def method(self):
            return {'key': key,}
    return A

class B(object):
    def method(self):
        return {'key': 'thisiswrong',}

BaseForC = generate_a(1337)

class C(B, BaseForC):
    def method(self):
        dict = super(C, self).method()
        dict.update({'other_key': 0,})
        return dict

EXPECTED = {'other_key': 0, 'key': 1337,}
RESULT = C().method()

if EXPECTED == RESULT:
    print("Ok")
else:
    print("EXPECTED: ", EXPECTED)
    print("RESULT: ", RESULT)
```

The question is - how do I choose which parent class I'm interested in?

Comment: This has become an entirely different question now.  If you want to call a specific base class, don't use `super()`, but call this base directly: `BaseForC.method(self)`.  Read the documentation of `super()` and the many old questions on `super()` on SO.

Comment: Of course! Sorry for this - its end of a workday and my brain just doesn't work like it should...

Answer (score 14):

Your `super()` call is wrong.  it should be

```
super(B, self).method()
```

or in Python 3.x also just

```
super().method()
```

Furthermore, don't use `dict` as a variable name -- this will shadow the built-in class.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake. Edited to correct my mistake and show my actual problem

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can call the parents method like this:

```
dict = BaseForC.method(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class B(BaseForB):
def method(self):
    dict = super(BaseForB, self).method()
    dict.update({'other_key': 0,})
    return dict
```

is not right, you should write like this:

```
class B(BaseForB):
def method(self):
    dict = super(B, self).method()
    dict.update({'other_key': 0,})
    return dict
```

In this situation:

```
class C(B, BaseForC):
def method(self):
    dict = super(C, self).method()
    dict.update({'other_key': 0,})
    return dict
```

you must use the old way to call Parent class's function. like this

```
class C(B, BaseForC):
def method(self):
    dict = B.method(self)
    dict.update({'other_key': 0,})
    return dict
```